# Angular: Disabled card after clicking

Tags: javascript, angular

I have three card that I show

```
<div *ngFor="let catalog of catalogs;let i=index" (click)="goToProducts(catalog)">
  <div>
    <div class="name-position text {{catalog.classe}}" style="font-size: 21px;">
      <img *ngIf="i == 1" style="max-width: 70%;" class="logo-catalog-header" src="assets/images/1.png" />
      <img *ngIf="i == 2" style="max-width: 70%;" src="assets/images/2.png" />
      <img *ngIf="i == 0" style="max-width: 70%;" src="assets/images/3.png" />
    </div>
    <div style="height: 50px;">
      <p *ngIf="i === 0" class="padd">P1 <br /></p>
      <p *ngIf="i == 1" class="padd">P2</p>
      <p *ngIf="i == 2" class="padd">P3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would try to disabled the card when clicked in one, how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

in goToProducts function you must set enabledCards to false in the end of function
enabledCards = false

You must define disabledCards in top level of your component class

```
enabledCards = true
```

and in goToProducts:

```
goToProducts(catalog) {
  if this.enabledCards { 
  ...your code
  }
  this.disabledCards = true
}
```

but you must think about time to set enabledCards to false

Comment: I'm trying, what I should add inside goToProducts?

Comment: You must define disabledCards in top level of your component

Comment: Ok I have understand this, I have defined disabledCards: any, and inside goToProducts(catalog){
  what should I insert ? 
 }

I don't understand

Comment: I am change the answer

Comment: Ok I have tried, the problem is at the beginning that now I didn't see the cards

Comment: yes my fail you must set disabledCards.includes(i) == false

Comment: I have tried also this one, now the card (image) disappears but I can click in other 2

Comment: You want disable all cards by one click?

Comment: Yes I would that when a card is clicked, the other cards aren't clickable

Comment: But this card must be clickable?

Comment: I prefer that no one cards is clickable after the first click

Comment: And last question clickable or visible?

Comment: they should be visible but not clickable, or not visible as you prefer :)

Comment: Now, i am understand you. Change my answer for you

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this
HTML file

```
<div *ngFor="let catalog of catalogs;let i=index" 
                            (click)="goToProducts(catalog)" >
                            <div>
                                <div class="name-position text {{catalog.classe}}" style="font-size: 21px;">
                                    <img *ngIf="i == 1" style="max-width: 70%;" class="logo-catalog-header"
                                        src="assets/images/1.png">
                                    <img *ngIf="i == 2" style="max-width: 70%;" src="assets/images/2.png"
                                        >
                                    <img *ngIf="i == 0" style="max-width: 70%;" src="assets/images/3.png"
                                        >
                                </div>
                                <div style="height: 50px">
                                    <p *ngIf="i === 0" class="padd" disabled="disable">P1 <br>
                                    </p>
                                    <p *ngIf="i == 1" class="padd" disabled="disable">P2</p>
                                    <p *ngIf="i == 2" class="padd" disabled="disable">P3</p>
                                </div>  
                        </div>
```

TS file

```
disable = false;

goToProducts(catalog){
this.disable = !this.disable;
}
```

Comment: I have tried what you suggest, but the problem is that I can click in another card while the first click card is loading.

Comment: I edited it try now

Comment: I can click in other cards :(

Comment: You're iterating three items and you wanna make all them disbale in one click am I right

Comment: yes, when click one on these, they should be disabled because I can click in another after the first click

Comment: Is the click necessary If not try giving `Disabled=true` in the parent `div`